# Socket.io not working on some machines

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, long-polling

I'm starting out with Socket.io, I made a quick example app and most things seemed to be working. However, when I tested it on a different PC in the office, it doesn't work. I've not been able to identify the problem or a common element. It works on an iMac in chrome and firefox, and a Windows machine running Firefox 15.0.1.

However on 2 other machines it does not work, they run Firefox 15.0.1 and the latest chrome. They can connect and receive broadcasts, but they won't send any broadcasts.

The example app provided with socket.io faces the same issues, so I know that my code isn't the issue.

The server is a rackspace virtual machine. The computers all share the same IP address, would this be the problem?

Thanks.

```
Connection I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr accepted.
debug - emitting heartbeat for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - set heartbeat interval for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
Connection 2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs accepted.
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs?t=1347888419067
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client 2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs
debug - emitting heartbeat for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - set heartbeat interval for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs?   t=1347888429074&i=0
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - clearing poll timeout
debug - jsonppolling writing io.j[0]("8::");
debug - set close timeout for client 2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs
debug - jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
debug - emitting heartbeat for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - set heartbeat interval for client I5m-GX0YxKk-fsqkaDYr
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs?t=1347888449506&i=0
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared close timeout for client 2_OfnBCUPoO1TuWUaDYs
^Croot@nodejs:~# node socket
info  - socket.io started
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized R840LL5ZZes1YFB_aZS8
debug - discarding transport
debug - jsonppolling received data packet �17�3:::Hello Server!�17�3:::Hello Server!
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized ycWCnVfgTTLAdi0maZS9
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized av8ttHujRRMUNdZWaZS-
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/av8ttHujRRMUNdZWaZS-
debug - set heartbeat interval for client av8ttHujRRMUNdZWaZS-
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
Connection av8ttHujRRMUNdZWaZS- accepted.
^Croot@nodejs:~# node socket
info  - socket.io started
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized tod2RUk4cC6njt7_ab1d
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/tod2RUk4cC6njt7_ab1d
debug - set heartbeat interval for client tod2RUk4cC6njt7_ab1d
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
Connection tod2RUk4cC6njt7_ab1d accepted.
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized Bm2b5koW4OhwMN0Uab1e
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/Bm2b5koW4OhwMN0Uab1e
debug - set heartbeat interval for client Bm2b5koW4OhwMN0Uab1e
debug - client authorized for 
debug - websocket writing 1::
Connection Bm2b5koW4OhwMN0Uab1e accepted.
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/Bm2b5koW4OhwMN0Uab1e?t=1347888478540
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client Bm2b5koW4OhwMN0Uab1e
debug - emitting heartbeat for client tod2RUk4cC6njt7_ab1d
debug - websocket writing 2::
debug - set heartbeat timeout for client tod2RUk4cC6njt7_ab1d
debug - got heartbeat packet
debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client tod2RUk4cC6njt7_ab1d
debug - set heartbeat interval for client tod2RUk4cC6njt7_ab1d
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/Bm2b5koW4OhwMN0Uab1e?t=1347888488546&i=0
debug - setting poll timeout
debug - discarding transport
debug - clearing poll timeout
```

Comment: have you checked out the respective browser's consoles for javascript errors or 404s? what exactly is the issue in the socket.io example app?

Comment: On the browsers that are facing the issue, they can receive broadcasts sent by the server, but they cannot instruct the server to send a broadcast. This works fine on some machines. The machines with the issues seem to be falling back to a xhr-polling method after waiting exactly 10 seconds. Don't think it can be a browser issue because the same versions are being used on the different machines.

Comment: Just had a breakthrough, setting the port to 443 seems to work. Why is this?

Comment: firewalls? 443 is common ssl, so it's often unblocked. Which port did you try previously?

Comment: when using this with express/some other http server, hooking socket.io into the same http server is a good idea. If your site then doesn't load over the network, it's probably a port thing and affects both normal http and websockets. In production you'd let the http server and socket.io share port 80, so users don't run into firewall issues.

Comment: Originally I was trying it on port 80, but it seems to be blocking websockets on this port, on some machines. It happened when node.js served the webpage, and when I hosted the sites on a separate PHP server that was connecting to the socket.io server. A test on http://websocketstest.com/ shows that everything can connect though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved this issue. An anti virus program was blocking the web sockets connection on a few of the machines. It took me a while to identify this issue because http://websocketstest.com/ showed all ports as open, and the software was showing that there was no firewall active. However, when exiting the antivirus program, everything started working again.

No idea why http://websocketstest.com/ shows that all ports are open though. Switched to port 843 for now.

Thanks